# Rust says the function parameter does not live enough, even though proper lifetime have been placed

Tags: generics, rust, closures, lifetime, trait-objects

For background context: I am creating an Observer/Subscriber based Global Event System (using single shared event systems). I decided to use `FnMut` as my callback closure. The lifetime `'a` placed at the `impl` of the makeshift struct `Data<'a>` should allow the `callback` parameter in the method `mut_func()` to live as long as the whole `Data` struct. Because the `callback` parameter uses the `F` generic which is definitely constrained by the lifetime `'a`. But the error is still appearing stating that the `callback` parameter does not live long enough.

I originally used `Box<T>` as my container for the `dyn FnMut(u32)`, but the `Box<T>` requires the callback to be `'static` (because I am casting the boxed generic into a box trait objects) which in my scenario is not achievable (for readability). I then tried to use `Rc<RefCell<T>>` which sadly does not support trait objects.

Also, I am using generics for `callback` parameter because I want that function to have higher readability instead of having to see `Box<T>` wrapping around an entire closure that *will* be everywhere, since this Event System will be my central part of my program. I will do anything to make the 'front-end' more readable and cleaner (except for significant performance impact).

Note: This is my example program. I can post the actual program if needed.

Error:

```rust
error[E0597]: `callback` does not live long enough
>  | impl<'a> Data<'a> {  
>  |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here  
>  |     fn mut_func<F: FnMut(u32) -> () + 'a>(&mut self, mut callback: F) {  
>  |         self.o.push(&mut callback as &mut dyn FnMut(u32) -> ());  
>  |         ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------------------------  
>  |         |           |  
>  |         |           borrowed value does not live long enough  
>  |         argument requires that `callback` is borrowed for `'a`  
>  |     }  
>  |     - `callback` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Example:

```rust
use std::any::Any;
use std::mem;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Event<'a> {
    obs: Vec<&'a mut dyn FnMut(u32) -> ()>,
}

impl<'a> Event<'a> {
    fn subscriber<F: FnMut(u32) -> () + 'a>(&mut self, mut callback: F) {
        self.o.push(&mut callback as &mut dyn FnMut(u32) -> ());
    }
}

fn main () {
    let mut e = Event {obs: Vec::new()};
    let x = 3;
    e.subscriber(|n| {x+n;});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the `callback` parameter uses the `F` generic which is definitely constrained by the lifetime `'a`. But the error is still appearing stating that the `callback` parameter does not live long enough.

`callback` lives long enough, but the problem is you're not storing the `callback` you received, you're storing it *converted to a trait object* (`dyn`) and that trait object's data has to be owned by something.

> I originally used `Box<T>` as my container for the `dyn FnMut(u32)`, but the `Box<T>` requires the callback to be `'static`

No it doesn't. This compiles:

```
struct Event<'a> {
    obs: Vec<Box<dyn FnMut(u32) -> () + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Event<'a> {
    fn subscriber<F: FnMut(u32) -> () + 'a>(&mut self, callback: F) {
        self.obs.push(Box::new(callback));
    }
}
```

Then with one more change, your example will compile: define `x` before `e` so that `x` lives longer than `e`:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 3;
    let mut e = Event {obs: Vec::new()};
    e.subscriber(|n| {x+n;});
}
```

[Rust Playground copy](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=304083330168b1428277e9756b99719b)

Comment: Well I forgot to say the `Box<T>` requires the `callback` to be `'static` because I need to convert that generic to a trait objects.

Comment: Nevermind. Actually I did not know you can just directly box a generic and it will automatically become a trait object?

Comment: @galaticExplorer it doesn't automatically become a trait object just because you box it, but [a type implementing a trait is *coercible* to the corresponding trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#unsized-coercions). So since you're *asking* for a trait object (by storing into a `Vec<Box<dyn>>`) rustc knows to look for a valid coercion, finds one, and everything's OK.